# Testing a Java Server-Client application using JUnit (or trying)

Tags: java, unit-testing, sockets, junit, client-server

I finished a Server-Client application in Java and I need to write multiple tests for different situations. For example I have a client and it sends a message and receives one message. Another case I have a client and it sends multiple messages and for every request it receives a message back. Another one I have 2 clients and each of them send multiple messages and for every message they receive something back. I have to mention my Server is a thread and my Clients are also threads because I need the main thread to do something else and I don't want to keep it in a busy waiting state and also the client and the server wait an unkown period of time for messages. Now I read something about JUnit and testing and I saw that those kinds of tests are used to test one class or one method at the time. I need to test multiple methods and I also have threads. I'm also working on local host so if those tests run conturently I don't know exactly what can happen to those socket ports. So if someone understands what I'm talking about you have any examples/ideas of how my tests should be? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to do some refactoring in order to write unit test, one idea would be to test a higher level, by writing Junit test that interact with the service running on localhost. These will be of a integration acceptance level of tests. But you need to bring some clarity and code to your question, otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: I solved it actually, writing tests normally and starting my server and clients on different ports specific to the test case seems to work pretty fine.